# SystemSoundID To Play Mp3 in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this method to play mp3 sounds in my app:

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

it play the mp3 sounds in iPhone4 and iPod 4 but in my iPad it won't Play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the MP3 to a CAFF:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 file.mp3 file.caf
```

This audio file will play on all iOS devices.